# How to highlight the "undefined method" in PyDev

Tags: pydev

I am coding with PyDev in Eclipse. It seems that PyDev can't highlight those "undefined methods" in my own class, e.g. self.do(). Could anybody give some clues about how to turn this on in preference, or PyDev current doesn't support this feature?

Thanks! 
Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature which was not added into PyDev because it's bound to give many false positives (because of the dynamic nature of Python), although it's surely doable...

Now, having said that, you can use PyLint (which does have that feature) integrated into PyDev.